# DJANGO persistant site wide memory

Tags: django, session, memory, post, memcached

I am new to Django, and probably using it in a way thats not normal.
That said, I would like to find a way to have site wide memory.
To Explain.

I have a very simple setup where one compter will make posts to the site every few seconds.
I want this data to be saved off somewhere.
I want everyone who is viewing the webpage to see updates based on this data in near real time via some javascript.

So using the sample code below.
Computer A would do a post to set_data and set data to "data set"
Computer B,C,D,etc.... would then do a get to get_data and see "data set"
Unfortunatly B,C,D just see ""

I have a feeling what i need is memcached, but I am on a hostgator shared server and cannot install that. In the meantime I am just writing them to files. This works but is really inneficient, and I am hopeing to serve a large user base.

Thanks for any help.

```
#view.py
data=""

def set_data(request):
    data = request.POST['data']
    return HttpResponse("");

def get_data(request):
    return HttpResponse(data);
```

Comment: If you want to push real-time updates to browser-based clients, you may want to look into "comet", e.g.: http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-and-comet/

Answer (score 2):

memcached is lossy, hence doesn't fulfil "persistent".

Files are fine, but switch to accessing them via [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html).

Comment: Thanks, but i am kinda confused how mmap helps. Seems that is useful if maybe your accessing a file many times in the same session. What i want is to read the file once, for 10,000 sessions. For reference I come from a controls type world where UDP packets fly fast and numerous. Web stuff is just mega different.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent storage is also called database (although for some cases Django's cache backend might work as well). Don't ever try to use global variables in web development.

Whether you should use a Django model or the cache backend really depends on your use case, but you just described a contrived example (or does your web app consist of a getter and a setter?).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really mean persistent storage, I need RAM not a hard drive. Why do you call my example contrived, its exactly what i need to do. Also, never really dealt with databases, but i assume that is a hard drive write every time i set data, which i would like to avoid. My system consists of a non-webpage program setting the data, and a webpage (hopefully many many webpages) accessing the data in near real time. Old data is thrown away, there is only ever like 20 bytes of data that needs stored at any one time.

Comment: For example if I were going to do this with a C# program, i could do this without ever accessing the file system and probably handle 10's of thousands of requests every second. I just prefer to get it done in django because this functionality is wrapped in a webpage.

Comment: @user602622: Ok, so if the use case is really that simple, you could make use of Django's memcached backend. Check out the [documentation on how to set it up](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached). But mind that if you restart the memcache daemon, your data will be lost. So depending on how often it gets updated, you maybe want to store it in a database - then retrieve it from memcached, and if memcached does not have the value available, fetch it from the database.

Comment: ok cool, will have to look into that if i ever get off of the shared hostgator server. They don't support memcached. And yeah, its real time data, so i absolutely do not care if I loose any data, it just has to hold it for 5 seconds serve it out to everyone, then receive the new value and serve that out for the next 5 seconds, repeat forever.(And if it goes down for 5 seconds a day, i couldn't care less.) Thanks for the info.